# I cannot save image to mysql database on django with ImageField. (django version: 2.1)

Tags: python, mysql, django, imagefield

When I am saving data with ImageField on django on sqlite db it's saving without any problem but when I am trying to save image on mySql database I am getting error like "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple". 
It's my code:

Settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}

...

MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/media")
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from subjects.models import Subjects


class Course(models.Model):
    subject = models.OneToOneField(Subjects, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_en
```

And I have also registered my model on admin.py to have permission. and I have also installed pillow to use ImageField.

It's an error:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/course/course/add/

Django Version: 2.1
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'subjects',
 'visit',
 'course']

Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner 
34. response = get_response(request)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response 
126. response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
124. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
607. return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
142. response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
44. response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
223. return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
1647. return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
45. return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
142. response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
1536. return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in _changeform_view
1575. self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_model
1094. obj.save()

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
717. force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
747. updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
830. result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
868. using=using, raw=raw)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
82. return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
1133. return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
1284. for sql, params in self.as_sql():

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
1237. for obj in self.query.objs

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in <listcomp>
1237. for obj in self.query.objs

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in <listcomp>
1236. [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in pre_save_val
1188. return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in pre_save
288. file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in save
87. self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in save
48. name = self.get_available_name(name, max_length=max_length)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in get_available_name
72. while self.exists(name) or (max_length and len(name) > max_length):

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in exists
308. return os.path.exists(self.path(name))

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in path
321. return safe_join(self.location, name)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
37. res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/learneng/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in location
201. return os.path.abspath(self.base_location)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py" in abspath
371. path = os.fspath(path)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/course/course/add/
Exception Value: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
```

Comment: You get this error while saving the image?

Comment: Yes. After submiting the form on admin page

Comment: It'd help to post the code where you save the image

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand you. Can you make it a little bit clear?

Comment: Did you change anything for the admin page?

Comment: No, I did not .